# Downloading data with complex types from Amazon Athena via JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, resultset, amazon-athena

When I try to run

```
// java.sql.ResultSet
val fieldNameData = resultSet.getObject("fieldName", classOf[Map[String, String]])
```

It throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: getObject
    at com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaResultSet.getObject(AthenaResultSet.java:1754)
```

It means that Athena JDBC driver doesn't support complex types such as map and array. What is another approach for downloading data with these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way is to use [Presto map functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) to convert map data into primitives the JDBC driver can work with.  The simplest is just to index into the map:

```
SELECT
  favorites['fruit'] as favorite_fruit,
  favorites['vegetable'] as favorite_vegetable
FROM
(
  SELECT
    MAP(ARRAY['fruit', 'vegetable'], ARRAY['apple', 'broccoli']) as favorites
) as food;
```

You could also use Presto's [UNNEST](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) syntax to join to a map and process it as rows in the results.  For example:

```
SELECT
  f.food_type,
  f.favorite_food
FROM
(
  SELECT
    MAP(ARRAY['fruit', 'vegetable'], ARRAY['apple', 'broccoli']) as favorites
) as food
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (favorites) AS f (food_type, favorite_food);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I decided to use another approach - just convert to JSON and download as a String.